# Trying to use "Difference" tool gives out "'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined" error

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-processing

I am trying to separate two overlapping vector layers and find out the difference in QGIS 2.18. I have tried finding difference with layers with points and also with buffers. Both of them give following error:

```
global name 'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined See log for more details
```

I have searched the web for this but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: To check the log go to 'Processing > History...' This explains the log better:  https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html.   At a guess it looks like a python issue with a variable 'WgsWKBTypes'.  I suggest updating your question with whatever the log says.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem was already fixed in the source code, see [the reported issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15766).

You have mainly 3 solutions:

**Mid term solution**

According to the [road map](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#qgis-release-schedule), QGIS 2.18.1 will be released in 25.11.2016, you'll get the fix with such version. Simply wait 22 days for it, OK?

### BUT

This is `free software`, so you can get the fix instantly!

**Short term solutions**

1. Install a nightly build. Check what packages are available for your operating system [here](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html).
2. Edit the file yourself.

   If you're on GNU/Linux, go to `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Difference.py` (on Windows it will be `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Difference.py`), and make sure line 32 looks like [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Difference.py#L32):

   ```
   from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsWKBTypes
   ```

   If you don't want to edit the file, you can just replace it, downloading the fixed file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Difference.py) (right click on the link and select `Save Link As...`).

   You will need administrator privileges to either edit or replace the file. After this, restart QGIS.

Comment: my Difference.py file looks like you write, but it didn't work anyway(

Answer (score 0):

other solution - 
Try Difference from SAGA vector polygon tools - it works!

[image]