# Trying to use “Pit Remove” tool gives out “'escapeAndJoin' is not defined” error

Tags: qgis, error, taudem

I have a similar question to this thread:

[Trying to use "Difference" tool gives out "'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined" error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216243/trying-to-use-difference-tool-gives-out-qgswkbtypes-is-not-defined-error)

According to image **[1]**, I've received this message when I trying to run TauDEM's Pit Remove algorithm in QGIS 2.18.5:

**global name 'escapeAndJoin' is not defined. See log for more details**.

I've located the file **TauDEMUtils.py** **[2]** but I'm not a programmer so I don't know what to do. Until now, there's no solution to this question.

My System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

---

**[1]** http://bit.ly/2nQfaeY
**[2]** http://bit.ly/2omCaQg

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the file TauDEMUtils.py. Just edit your file (you'll need administrative privileges - e.g sudo) as shown in this link:

https://fossies.org/diffs/QGIS-final/2_14_9_vs_2_14_10/python/plugins/processing/algs/taudem/TauDEMUtils.py-diff.html

Comment: There is a problem with the code in the above link. When I tried it, the TauDEM command was changed to:
m p i e x e c - n 2 p i t r e m o v e - z D : / j u n k / 4 G P r o j e c t s / T u t o r i a l P r o j e c t 1 / L i d a r / q 4 7 1 2 2 b 3 2 b e . t i f - f e l C : \ U s e r s \ L E N N Y ~ 1 . E N G \ A p p D a t a \ L o c a l \ T e m p \ p r o c e s s i n g 4 7 e 0 4 f a e 6 c 6 9 4 3 6 f 9 d 2 f 7 a c d 6 4 2 3 4 8 4 5 \ 3 1 1 9 e d 7 7 3 a f 5 4 e 7 9 a 4 0 2 d 8 b 8 7 d f 9 3 b 2 3 \ f e l . t i f" It adds a space between each character. I can't believe that I am the only one experi

Comment: Hi Robotuner. This issue was fixed in QGIS 2.18.6 point release, but now we have a 2.18.7 in official site. See this info here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16366